# Уменьшается размер файла при записи в Java

Tags: java, изображения, opencv

Есть bytearray, в котором хранятся байты картинки. Читал их с помощью OpenCV Imgcodecs.imread(). После этого сразу же записал их двумя способами в файл:

```
byte[] imageInByte = null;

Image image = new Image("./1.jpg");
BufferedImage im = ImageTransform.toBitmap(image);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
  ImageIO.write(im, "jpg", baos);

  imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

  baos.close();

  // convert byte array back to BufferedImage
  InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
  BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

  // 1 способ
  ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File("./2.jpg"));

  // 2 способ
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./2_fos.jpg");
  fos.write(imageInByte);
  fos.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Исходный файл весит 104Kb. После сохранения фотографий двумя способами, они стали весить 49Kb. 
Вопрос: почему так, если никаких изменений в байты я не вносил? Можно было бы сослаться на OpenCV, мол, сжимает и т.д., но тогда почему и с помощью FileOutputStream сохраняется картинка с таким же размеров в Kb. Предполагаю, что при чтении картинки с помощью OpenCV Imgcodecs.imread(), оно заранее ужимает.

Comment: Воспроизводится ли ситуация, с открытием только что сохраненного OpenCV файла и сохранением его же? Если нет, то просто кодеки OpenCV используют другое сжатие.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Не могли бы вы пояснить?

Comment: Проделайте всё тоже самое с файлом 2.jpg будет ли разница в размере?

Comment: Еще почитайте про .jpg особенно про сжатие https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#.D0.A1.D0.B6.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B5

Comment: С сжатием я работал и в CPU и в CUD'e как раз-таки с преобразованием RGB в YCbCr. Сейчас попробую со вторым файлом проделать то же самое

Comment: Разницы не наблюдаю (я говорю о чтении/записи второго файла).

Comment: Т.е. 2.jpg весил  49Kb, вы его открыли, сохранили в 3.jpg и весит он тоже  49Kb?

Comment: "Т.е. 2.jpg весил 49Kb, вы его открыли, сохранили в 3.jpg и весит он тоже 49Kb?" - верно.

Comment: Просто OpenCV использует другой кодек

Comment: получается, что всё норм? может можно как-то кодек поменять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кодек, который сохраняет jpg в OpenCV использует шкалу сжатия, от 0 до 100, где 100 - отсутствие сжатия.

Сохранение jpg без сжатия из Mat *mat*:

```
MatOfInt param = new MatOfInt(Imgcodecs.CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 200);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("jpgWithnoutCompress.jpg", mat, param);
```

Стандартно значение сжатия 95 *(вроде бы, специально не проверял)*